# Copied or Restored Azure SQL Database Using Same Name of Database Not Copying/Restoring Properly

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have two Azure SQL Databases in an elastic pool. They are named Web and Web2. These are attached to deployment slots and move with the swap so that either Web or Web2 will be the database serving public traffic (primary slot).

Once they are swapped, I want to update the data of the non public Web database (which could be Web or Web2) so they are in sync.

To achieve this, I have a PowerShell script that finds which database is in the primary slot. Then I tried using the geo-restore of a database to create a new database named RestoredDB that I then rename to either Web or Web2 so I keep my connectionString intact... OR I tried the copy Azure SQL database command.

Geo-Restore Example

```
$GeoBackup = Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01"
Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "TargetResourceGroup" -ServerName "TargetServer" -TargetDatabaseName "RestoredDatabase" -ResourceId $GeoBackup.ResourceID -ElasticPoolName "MyWebPool"
```

Copy Azure SQL DB Example:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -CopyDatabaseName <String> -CopyResourceGroupName <String> -CopyServerName <String> -DatabaseName db1 -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -ServerName s1 -ElasticPoolName "MyWebPool"
```

In either instance, it would create the RestoredDB with the correct size in GB as the source I want to restore or copy from... but upon deleting the non-active Web (either Web or Web2) and renaming RestoredDB to Web or Web2... it reverts back to the original Web or Web2 instead of being the RestoredDB that has the correct data just renamed to the desired database to prevent updating the connectionStrings.

Is this because of Geo-Redundant backups (7 days retention), where I need to create a unique database name instead of deleting the original database and renaming my newly created or restored to database?

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-running the same script it is working. Perhaps my previous script that had the restore operation was cached in Azure DevOps. The steps I am using are as follows:

1. Get the live database name from the Azure App Service ConnectionStrings
2. Create a copy of the live database (either Web or Web2 depending on which DB is currently swapped in)
3. Delete the non-live database (either Web or Web2 depending on which DB is currently swapped in)
4. Rename the copied database to be the name of what was in the non-live slot